# could not update rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchrest

```
class Student < CouchRest::Model::Base
   collection_of :phones
   def add_phone(new_phone)
     #this does not work
     #new_phone_ids_list = phone_ids << new_phone.id 
     #this works
     new_phone_ids_list = phone_ids + [new_phone.id]
     self.update_attributes(:phone_id => new_phone_ids_list)
   end
end
```

The difference is when I use phone_ids << new_phone.id to create a new list and update couchdb, it doesn't work. But if I use phone_ids + [new_phone.id] ,updates will work. I understand `phone_ids + [new_phone.id]` will return a new instance, but cannot figure out why `phone_ids << new_phone.id`  doesnt work

Comment: "Any manual changes made to the collection ids property (group_ids), unless replaced, will require a reload of the CollectionOfProxy for the two sets of data to be in sync" http://www.rubydoc.info/github/couchrest/couchrest_model/CouchRest%2FModel%2FAssociations%2FClassMethods%3Acollection_of

Comment: @bumpy Thank you very much!!! this is exactly what I am looking for!!!!

Comment: @bumpy I don't know how to mark your answer as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Any manual changes made to the collection ids property (group_ids), unless replaced, will require a reload of the CollectionOfProxy for the two sets of data to be in sync

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/couchrest/couchrest_model/CouchRest%2FModel%2FAssociations%2FClassMethods%3Acollection_of

Answer (score 0):

Try to add using directly to hash:

```
new_phone_ids_list << new_phone.id
self.update_attributes(:phone_id => new_phone_ids_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried, it doesn't work. Same result as `new_phone_ids_list = phone_ids << new_phone.id ` got.